# Rails worker not querying up-to-date Active Record model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a worker that is creating an entry into ActiveRecord using the following syntax:

```
unique_id = SecureRandom.hex(32)
user = User.find(10)
user.tasks.build(tk: unique_id, completed: false).save
```

However, further down I have a statement that is supposed to monitor the record to see if anything changes, with the following:

```
while !Task.find_by(tk: unique_id, completed: false).nil?
   sleep 5
end
```

This record is managed by a background worker and eventually marks `completed` as `true`.

However, this never finishes because it seems that the `completed` attribute is *always* false, even if I go into the database to see that it's not. It's like some type of caching is involved. As you can see in the figure below, the first command shows that the record id of `19` has a `completed` attribute that equals `true`; however, the second one (which is being used in the worker) shows that it's not.

[image: example]

How do I disable caching in my workers so that it's always pulling the latest information from the database?

Comment: for this line: `user.tasks.build(tk: unique_id, completed: false).save`, shouldn't it be `completed: true`?

Comment: Nope @james. It's creating the record in ActiveRecord and I have another background worker that marks it as `true` later. I want this to proceed only after it's marked as true. Updating OP to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by using `.reload` on the actual record itself. For example:

```
data = user.tasks.build(tk: unique_id, completed: false)
data.save
```

and when needing to see its refreshed values, I just called:

```
data.reload
if data.completed == true
   break
end
```